# Multiple sheetnames and wanting to find a dynamic way to code functions that needed activesheet("sheetname")

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, i have 4 different sheetnames such as SheetA, SheetB, SheetC, SheetD.  I utilized the code below so that when a file is being imported, my VBA codes allow it to be placed at the correct respective sheets.

```
If InStr(filename, "SheetA") > 0 Then
   Call ImportSheetAfile(path, filename)
```

```
worksheets("SheetA").Cells(56,1)=  Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("SheetA")).Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
```

To apply the code above, is there a way to code such that i do not need to paste this line in all 4 import subroutines? I wanted to find the max number in all 4 sheets and wanted to find a dynamic way to code around it.

Comment: So, do you want a single code able to deal with those four sheets? If so, why do you name them as "finename"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, please use the next code:

```
Sub runOnFourSheets()
 Dim arrSheets, filename As String, lastRow As Long
 
 arrSheets = Split("SheetA,SheetB,SheetC,SheetD", ",")
 For Each filename In arrSheets
    Call ImportSheetAfile(Path, filename)
    lastRow = Worksheets(filename).Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    Worksheets(filename).cells(56, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets(filename)).Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Chewjunnie: Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, isn't it what you want?

Comment: At the call part, can i add "Call ImportSheetBfile(Path, filename)", "Call ImportSheetCfile(Path, filename)", "Call ImportSheetDfile(Path, filename)"?

Comment: @Chewjunnie :Why should you do that? Do you understand the above code? At least, did you test it? If yes, didn't it do what you want? If not, you should edit your question and show us how `ImportSheetAfile` code looks. Maybe there are mistakes, not referring to the sheet argument.

Comment: @Chewjunnie: Still alive? I could see that you placed a new question. What about this one?